# Problema ao chamar Teclado Virtual - WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um botão que ao clicar o teclado virtual do windows é chamado.

```
Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

Ao clicar no botão uma Exception é disparada:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

Ja pesquisei em vários lugares, por isto estou fazendo a pergunta.
Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Não seria o caso de você passar todo o caminho onde está este executável? Acredito que a aplicação esteja procurando na pasta da solution, e não vai encontrar o executável lá.

Comment: O mesmo acontece usando @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\osk.exe".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929255

Comment: Consegui, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui com o seguinte código:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);

private const UInt32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
private const UInt32 SC_RESTORE = 0xf120;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private string OnScreenKeyboadApplication = "osk.exe";

private void btnKeyboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Process.Start("osk.exe");

            string processName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OnScreenKeyboadApplication);

            // Check whether the application is not running 
            var query = from process in Process.GetProcesses()
                        where process.ProcessName == processName
                        select process;

            var keyboardProcess = query.FirstOrDefault();

            // launch it if it doesn't exist
            if (keyboardProcess == null)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(); ;
                bool sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect = false;

                // Disable x64 directory virtualization if we're on x64,
                // otherwise keyboard launch will fail.
                if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                {
                    sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref ptr);
                }

                // osk.exe is in windows/system folder. So we can directky call it without path
                using (Process osk = new Process())
                {
                    osk.StartInfo.FileName = OnScreenKeyboadApplication;
                    osk.Start();
                }

                // Re-enable directory virtualisation if it was disabled.
                if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                    if (sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect)
                        Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(ptr);
            }
            else
            {
                // Bring keyboard to the front if it's already running
                var windowHandle = keyboardProcess.MainWindowHandle;
                SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, new IntPtr(SC_RESTORE), new IntPtr(0));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Experimente desta forma:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "osk.exe"),
    Verb = "runas"
};

Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Ao definir a propriedade `Verb = "runas"` estamos a "dizer" ao Windows para se comportar como se o processo tivesse sido evocado pelo comando "*Correr como Administrador*".